# Sprite onAreaTouched not called in Android API level 10 device

Tags: android, listener, andengine, sprite, scene

I am developing live wallpaper, in that I need listener for sprite and scene.

listener is called in API level 14 device but it is not working in API level 10.

**My code:**

**Sprite listener:**

```
Sprite chain = new Sprite(getSpriteXPos(), getSpriteYPos(),
            getDisplyImage(), getVbom())

    {
        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
            switch (pSceneTouchEvent.getAction()) {
            case TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                break;
            case TouchEvent.ACTION_UP:

                break;

            case TouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                break;

            }
            return true;
        }
    };
```

**Scene listener:**

```
public class HeartWall extends BaseScene implements IOnSceneTouchListener{

@Override
public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
    Log.e("", "TAP");
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: `but it is not working` - ????.  The sprite doesn't move?  The method is not called?  The app crashes?  Your trousers catch fire?  The sun stops shining?

Comment: Yes. Method is not called. No crash.

Comment: Anyone.??? please help me out.